# Open a new PowerPoint presentaation without template view

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, templates

How can I open PowerPoint in a new default template without it first opening the template view? I seldom use the `cool` PowerPoint templates that Microsoft offers. I just want to start a new presentation.

I apologize upfront, if there is already a duplicate answer. I tried to look for it but could not find it.

Here is what I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the option of Blank Presentation.

This will create a presentation with one empty slide.

---

If you wish to avoid this step, open the menu *File > Options*,
General tab, uncheck "Show the Start screen when this application starts",
then click OK.

[image]

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, but I want to save one click, I don't want it to go to template view to let me select. When I click PowerPoint from Start Menu, I want it to open a new blank presentation.

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I wanted.